# How to typing annotate additional obligatory parameter when using ParamSpec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I want to wrap a function call with some pre action and post action and also make sure that the caller has set the key parameter. I am trying with the following:

```
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def urlparams_pre(key: str):
    return key

def urlparams_post(key: str, ret: R) -> R:
    return ret

def urlparams_call(fn: Callable[P, R], *args: P.args, key: str, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
   urlparams_pre(key)
   ret = fn(*args, key=key, **kwargs)
   urlparams_post(key, ret)
   return ret
```

However, `pyright` complains about that `fn` does not take `key=key` parameter, and that inside `urlparams_call` the `key:` can't be after `P.args`.

How do I fix it?

This will be used to set url query parameters from `streamlit.*` functions. For example `urlparams_call(st.text_input, "input your text", value="initial value", key="input")` will add a `&input=initial+value` to query and properly react to changes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you can do is this:

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def urlparams_pre(key: str):
    return key

def urlparams_post(key: str, ret: R) -> R:
    return ret

def urlparams_call(
    fn: Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R],
    key: str,
    *args: P.args,
    **kwargs: P.kwargs
) -> R:
    urlparams_pre(key)
    ret = fn(key, *args, **kwargs)
    urlparams_post(key, ret)
    return ret
```

We can use `Concatenate` to add additional positional arguments to the inferred `ParamSpec`.

So we can do something like:

```py
def func(name: str, a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

result = urlparams_call(func, "hello", 2, 3)
reveal_type(result)
```

...and it type-checks ok.

But the restriction is that you have to be ok calling `fn` like `fn(key, *args, **kwargs)` with `key` as a positional arg, I don't think there's any way to add a new keyword arg to the `ParamSpec`.